# Using Moment to Validate Default Javascript Date Format

Tags: javascript, validation, date, momentjs

I want to use moment (or any other method) to validate a particular string as a valid date value based on the default javascript date format.

I have the following code:

```
var date = new Date(); // Tue Nov 28 2017 17:54:41 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

I want to take that string output and use moment to validate that as a valid date string. I know I can do this:

```
moment(date, moment.ISO_8601).isValid();
```

But there is a problem. Here are the results for the same date values:

```
moment(new Date(), moment.ISO_8601).isValid(); //True
moment("Tue Nov 28 2017 17:54:41 GMT-0600 (CST)", moment.ISO_8601).isValid() //False
```

Which is not what I want since both of them should be true. I can't do `new Date(...)` because here's the results for that approach:

```
moment(new Date("Tue Nov 28 2017 17:54:41 GMT-0600 (CST)"), moment.ISO_8601).isValid(); //True
moment(new Date("3"), moment.ISO_8601).isValid(); //True
```

This also is not what I want since the second line should be false.

How do I properly valid a string as a valid date only if it strictly follows the format `Tue Nov 28 2017 17:54:41 GMT-0600 (CST)`?

I have researched everywhere to understand what format `Tue Nov 28 2017 17:54:41 GMT-0600 (CST)` is but I can't find anything. It's not ISO 8601 and not RFC 2822 either.

Comment: what makes you think that `new Date()` produce a string?

Comment: @Sag1v I'm not really saying it does, I'm just saying I have a string in that format

Comment: There is no "default javascript date format". The output from *Date.prototype.toString* is implementation dependent and varies from browser to browser and host to host. However, an implementation is required to correctly parse the output produced by its own *toString* (but not that of others). If the result of parsing a string is an invalid Date, then the [*toString*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.todatestring) method is required to return the string "Invalid Date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RobG stated in the comments *There is no "default javascript date format". The output from Date.prototype.toString is implementation dependent*

Since your input is neither in ISO 8601 nor in RFC 2822 Date time formats you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) using `'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z'` as format parameter. If you want that your string matches *strictly* your format, you can use [strict mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) (`moment(String, String, Boolean)`).

Please note that moment does not provide token for parsing timezone abbreviation (e.g. `CST`), so your input will not be recognized in strict mode. Here an example of parsing using both strict and forgiving mode; `myIsValid` function is an example of removing timezone abbreviation from the input.

```js
var s = 'Tue Nov 28 2017 17:54:41 GMT-0600 (CST)';
var fmt = 'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z';

console.log(moment(s, fmt).isValid());
console.log(moment(s, fmt, true).isValid());

function myIsValid(input){
  // Check if input contains ()
  var idxl = input.indexOf('(');
  var idxr = input.indexOf(')');
  if( idxl>0 && idxr>0 ){
    // Remove timezone abbreviation
    input = input.substr(0, idxl-1);
  }
  var fmt = 'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z';
  return moment(input, fmt, true).isValid();
}

console.log(myIsValid(s));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Lastest version of moment (`2.19.2`), gives Invalid Date even with forgiving mode. Using `parsingFlags()` you see that `weekdayMismatch` is `true`, I think <del>this is an issue of the 2.19+ version of moment</del> this is related to moment [#4227](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4227) issue.

```js
var s = 'Tue Nov 28 2017 17:54:41 GMT-0600 (CST)';
var fmt = 'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z';
var m1 = moment(s, fmt);
var m2 = moment(s, fmt, true);
console.log(m1.isValid());
console.log(m1.parsingFlags());
console.log(m2.isValid());
console.log(m2.parsingFlags());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strictly validate a timestamp with Moment.js, use the strict flag when parsing:

```js
var s = 'Tue Nov 28 2017 17:54:41 GMT-0600';
s = s.replace('GMT','');
console.log('Modified string: ' + s);

var mStrict = moment(s, 'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ', true);
console.log('Strict parse: ' + mStrict.format());

var mLoose  = moment(s, 'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');
console.log('Loose parse : ' + mLoose.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

However, for me both strict and loose produce "Invalid date", which is incorrect (and should be "Invalid Date"). The issue seems to be the timezone value or token.